# Nodejs http server cannot handle, proxy enabled request from Amazon Load balancer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodeja HTTP server which was woking good until I enabled Proxy at amazon Load balancer (which is on TCP protocol) to get client's IP.
I wonder How TCP server of nodejs works perfectly , but http server cannot

```
var net = require('net');
var proxy_protocol = require('node-proxy-protocol');

net.createServer(function(socket) {
        proxy_protocol.parse(socket, function(error, obj) {
             console.log(obj);    //returns required client's info
        });
 });
```

but, why http server fails to do , if I replace "net" with "http":

```
This does not work
var net = require('http');
var proxy_protocol = require('node-proxy-protocol');

http.createServer(function(req,res) {
        proxy_protocol.parse(req, function(error, obj) {
             console.log(obj);    //returns nothing
        });
 });
```

although I know that HTTP (usually) operates over TCP, so it must work for both.
basically I think, My Http Server is not able to handle TCP request from Load Balancer.
Please let me know where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My nodejs HTTP server was not handling TCP from Load Balancer, so I switched Load Balancer's Protocol to HTTP.and now my HTTP server works well.